# Hibernate Duplicate entry '7090' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Im getting following error when the application tries to insert a record row in the db.

```
SQL Error: 1062, SQLState: 23000
ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Duplicate entry '7089' for key      'PRIMARY'
ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Could not synchronize   database state with session
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Duplicate entry '7090' for key 'PRIMARY'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1269)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:955)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
```

The definition is

```
@Id
@Column(name = "CST_CUSTOMER_ID_PK")
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

The part at which the error occurs is :

```
savedCustomer = customerDao.save(customer);
            mtmrsLogger.debug("saved customer id:" + savedCustomer.getId());
            /**
             * Updating Customer Trans Table
             */
            updateCustomerTransForMakerChecker(customer,     customerform.getAuditDetails());

            /**
             * Updating Customer Audit
             */
            updateCustomerAuditForMakerChecker(customer, customerform.getAuditDetails());
            //status=1;
            //Add customer ewallet account
            updateCustomerInWalletBalance(customer, customerform.getAuditDetails());
            //send sms to customer
            smsManager.sendSMSToCUCustomer(customer.getMobileno(), userBean);
        }
        mtmrsLogger.exiting("CustomerManagerImpl", "addCustomer");
```

My log shows, program has reached ' Exiting Class: CustomerManagerImpl Method: addCustomer' this part. Im saving the customer ,im setting the same entry in other two tables. The primary key of customer table is foreigh key in other two tables. Im lost please help.

```
CREATE TABLE `CST_CUSTOMER_INFO` (
`CST_CUSTOMER_ID_PK` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`CST_MOBILE` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
   `CST_FIRST_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`CST_LAST_NAME` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`CST_MIDDLE_NAME` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`CST_CUSTOMER_ID_PK`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4103 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Im getting error occassionally in production , but in local its ok..

Comment: Production environment is clustered?

Comment: Nope, but the insertion is being done by one other app too. By the time this application tries to insert the row with 7091 row id, the table already has got upto 7095.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As table is being modified by more than one application, use of `@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")` will result in ambiguity.

**Explanation**

> Strategy increment :  It generates identifiers of type long, short or
>   int that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into
>   the same table. It should not be used in the clustered environment.

So you should rethink what strategy is to be used to generate id's. Using `sequence` or `native` strategy can resolve your problem.

Comment: Can is just remove the generation part, ie  @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "increment")
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator") ,
So that only db ddl increment will be used to increment the row value?

Comment: `@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "identity")` would suffice in your case as you are using `auto_increment` for table id. Please go through http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id to understand best strategy for your case.

Comment: I used identity strategy, it seems its working now. Thanks (Y)

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
`CST_CUSTOMER_ID_PK` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

with

```
`CST_CUSTOMER_ID_PK` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
```

You are incrementing the id using hibernate/java, no need to make the DBMS increment it also.

Comment: Does hibernate put the latest rowid in cache? or when the point of saving, it takes from the table and increment by one? If latter, than i shouldnt be getting the issue.  And  i cant remove auto increment form DB because, the other app is using auto increment to insert the row.

Comment: If you have AUTO_INCREMENT, then you don't need to increment the id inside java.